# Gazebo 6 update rate settings

Tags: gazebo-6

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am working with Gazebo 6 and I would like to decrease CPU consommation.

I saw many post on this and for example this one : http://answers.ros.org/question/35699/gazebo-real-and-simulation-time/

But when I try to set the update rate to a negative value in the world file, Gazebo run as fast as possible (gzserver at 305% CPU on an empty world).

```
<physics type="ode">
        <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
        <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
        <real_time_update_rate>-1</real_time_update_rate>
        <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
</physics>
```

I would like the simulation to run real time factor without using 100% CPU for an empty world.

Is this behavior should work with max_step_size set to 0.001 and real_time_update_rate set to 1000 ?

Is there a configuration problem with my computer ? (I7 - nvidia GTX 850m)

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13226/gazebo-6-update-rate-settings/) by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 284 on 2016-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A negative value for  `<real_time_update_rate>` will cause Gazebo to run as fast as possible, and will therefore consume as much CPU as possible.

If you want to run in real time, set the `<real_time_update_rate>` to be `1.0/<max_step_size>`.

When I run `gzserver` with an empty world, I get around 7.3% CPU usage. Can you try running just `gzserver`?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on 2016-05-11**:
I run gzserver as you said and I have 6% CPU usage. When I run an empty world using roslaunch and launch file I get 13 % CPU usage for gzserver. But gzclient is always at 100% CPU usage. Is this the expected behavior ?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-05-11**:
Running gzserver through roslaunch shouldn't double the CPU usage. That requires some exploration. Gzclient will consume 100% CPU.

**Comment by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on 2016-05-18**:
Ok thanks for your answer.